# Broadcom storcli64 - add unconfigured good disk as hotspare

Tags: raid, broadcom, storcli

as a disclaimer, I am not particularly well versed with storcli so please bare with me.

I have an existing RAID configuration that I took over from a colleague who since left.
One disk failed and I have managed to bring it back online and successfully removed the foreign status.

```
Drive Information :
=================

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model            Sp Type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
8:5      14 UGood -  7.276 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST8000NM0075     U  -
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to use this disk as hotspare disk but am not allowed to add it ..

```
FooBar:~ # storcli64 /c0 /e8 /s5 add hotsparedrive dgs=0
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Add Hot Spare Failed.

Detailed Status :
===============

----------------------------------------------
Drive     Status  ErrCd ErrMsg
----------------------------------------------
/c0/e8/s5 Failure   255 Device state invalid.
----------------------------------------------
```

I am grateful for any hint what I am doing wrong or how to resolve this.

Thanks
T.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else is struggling with the same issue .. the disk needs to be initialized.

```
FooBar:~ # storcli64 /c0 /e8 /s5 start initialization
```

and you can then check on the status using

```
FooBar:~ # storcli64 /c0 /e8 /s5 show initialization
```

After the process finishes, the add hotsparedrive command succeeded.